# (Anti)commutation of ghosts and fermions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, constrained-dynamics, quantization

I would like to ask whether fermionic Grassmann fields in a gauge theory path integral (say in QCD) should be chosen to commute or anticommute with ghost and anti-ghost fields. The way most textbooks present it suggests that anti-commutation should be chosen, but I don't know any argument for this. There is also the question of (anti)commutation relations for corresponding operators in the [Krein space](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Krein_space).

I was asked in the comments where this issue ever came up. It was in derivation of the conserved BRS current in QCD. Let me first explain that in many books it is stated that BRS operator $s$ satisfies graded Leibniz rule with respect to the fermion number, for example $s ( \bar \psi \psi ) = (s \bar \psi ) \psi - \bar \psi s \psi  $. On a lecture about anomalies I attended recently it was stated that Leibniz rule graded with respect to the ghost number should be used instead (or at least can be used), so $s ( \bar \psi \psi ) = (s \bar \psi ) \psi + \bar \psi s \psi$ but $s (c^a c^b)=(sc^a) c^b - c^a (s c^b)$. Therefore I am naturally led to consider variations of fields of the form $\phi \to \phi + \epsilon s \phi$, where $\epsilon$ is a Grassmann parameter commuting with $A, \psi, \bar \psi$ but anticommuting with $c^a$ and $\bar c^a$. I found that under these transformations variation of action takes the form
$$ \delta S = \int d^4 x (\partial_{\mu} \epsilon) \left[ - F_a^{\mu \nu} D_{\nu} c^a + g \bar \psi \gamma^{\mu} c^a t_a \psi + b^a D^{\mu} c^a - \frac{1}{2} g f_{abc} (\partial^{\mu} \bar c^a) c^b c^c \right]. $$
We see that inside the parenthesis $[]$ we have a conserved current, from now denoted $J_{\mathrm{BRS}}^{\mu}$. After manipulating this current using the equations of motion I found a term $g [\bar \psi, c^a] \gamma^{\mu} t_a \psi$. It turns out that explicit evaluation of the divergence of $J_{\mathrm{BRS}}^{\mu}$ using equations of motion gives zero only if this commutator is taken to be zero. Thus it seems to me that this is the only choice consistent with my choice of the definition of the BRS operator.

**Remark** I used the Lagrangian
$$ \mathcal L = - \frac{1}{4} F^2 + \bar \psi (i \gamma \cdot D - M) \psi + \partial_{\mu} \bar c^a D^{\mu}c^a - A^a_{\mu} \partial^{\mu} b^a + \frac{1}{2} \xi b^2 , $$
with covariant derivative $D=\partial + ig A$.

Comment: Can you write down a term in which this matters?

Comment: Dear @marmot in some calculations (related to BRST operator) I did in QCD I found a term $\bar \psi c^a t_a \psi - c^a \bar \psi t_a \psi$. It vanishes if the ghost field commutes with spinor fields, but not otherwise.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if you want to add the derivation of the term to the question.

Comment: @Blazej could you elaborate on how this term enters your calculation and why is it necessary? Physically, ghosts and fermions *do not couple* to each other. In fact, ghosts are merely a perturbative way to accomodate for the correction to the Yang-Mills path integral measure coming from gauge-fixing. Are you using a gauge-fixing condition involving fermions?

Comment: Dear @marmot and  Solenodon Paradoxus, I edited my question to specify where my problem arises.

Comment: The simple mentioning of Krein spaces got me interested, however, I see this not pursued, so I am disappointed.

Comment: Which page in _Anomalies in QFT_ by Bertlmann?

Comment: @DanielC, Krein spaces are mentioned because ultimately one would also like to turn all the fields into operators, which act in a space with indefinite signature. As far as I understand the appropriate mathemathical structure for these spaces is Krein space, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Dear @Qmechanic , I'm sorry, I checked now and it seems that I got confused by some sentence in Bertlmann. This means that I don't have a reliable written reference for the approach I'm trying to apply. I learned about it on a lecture and I will ask our lecturer for some references.

Comment: For anyone potentially interested about this in the future I note that if it is assumed that BRS operator satisfies Leibniz rule graded with respect to the fermion number then the same BRS current is obtained up to modification of the sign in the fermionic term. Thus after applying EOMs we see that for conservation it is required that $\bar \psi$ and $c^a$ anticommute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not completely clear what OP is looking for, but here are some hopefully helpful comments:

1. Classically (meaning when Planck constant $\hbar\to 0$), two fields $A$ and $B$ are super-commutative $$AB~=~(-1)^{|A||B|}BA,$$
   where $|A|$ and $|B|$ denote the corresponding Grassmann-parity. 
   In other words, the classical super-commutator 
   $$[A,B]~\equiv~AB-(-1)^{|A||B|}BA~=~0$$
   vanishes.
2. The super-commutator in quantum theory is typically a quantum deformation of the classical super-commutator.
3. Note that ghost fields can both be Grassmann-even and Grassmann-odd, depending on the theory.
4. In principle, one may consider [superalgebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superalgebra) with several independent $\mathbb{Z}_2$- or $\mathbb{Z}$-gradings $$|\cdot|_1, \quad \ldots, \quad  |\cdot|_n. $$
   The super-commutator in such a superalgebra is then defined as
   $$[A,B]~\equiv~AB-(-1)^{\sum_{i=1}^n|A|_i|B|_i}BA.$$
   (For instance, one could consider exterior form degree and usual Grassmann-grading as two independent gradings.)
5. A theory may allow for different conventions. The main point is that one should be consistent.
6. Specifically, concerning fermion matter fields $\psi$, Faddeev-Popov ghost field $c$ and antighost fields $\bar{c}$ in Yang-Mills theory, it is possible to consistently set up the BRST formulation using only one type of Grassmann-grading, in which $\psi$, $c$ and $\bar{c}$ are all Grassmann-odd, and pairwise anti-commuting.

Comment: Dear @Qmechanic mathematically we can have a situation where we have two indepedent Grassmann algebras, generated by $\eta_i$ and $\xi_i$, so that $ \{ \xi_i , \xi_j \}  = \{ \eta_i , \eta_j \}=0$ but $[\eta_i, \xi_j]=0$. The question is whether such construction is implemented is quantum field theories.

Comment: Dear @Qmechanic , please note that I edited my question to specify where precisely the problem arises and what led me to believing that $[c^a,\psi]=0$ (on the level of integration variables) is the consistent definition in the approach I am using.

Comment: I accept this answer, even though the question whether convention with BRS operator taken as graded with respect to the ghost number is acceptable is still open for me. However it is not strictly speaking the question I originally asked, and it might be very dificult to give a definite answer.